# template not displaying information - django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I can't figure out why my data won't display in my user.html template. From reviewing the code it looks like everything is linked correctly. The users.html page is showing up on the website minus the information about {{ user.order_set.all }}. I have highlighted the code I believe relates to the issue. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

user.html - html for displaying the data

```
{% extends "fuisce/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

**{{ user.order_set.all }}**


{% endblock content %}
```

views.py - order

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your views here.

from carts.models import Cart

from .models import Order
from users.models import Profile 

from .utils import id_generator

**def orders(request):
    context = {}
    template = "orders/user.html"
    return render(request, template, context)**

def checkout(request):
    try:
        the_id = request.session['cart_id']
        cart = Cart.objects.get(id=the_id)
    except:
        the_id = None
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))

    new_order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(cart=cart)
    if created:
        new_order.order_id = id_generator()
        new_order.save()
    my_p = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    new_order.user = my_p
    new_order.save()

    if new_order.status == "Finished":
        # cart.delete()
        del request.session['cart_id']
        del request.session['items_total']
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))


    context = {}
    template = "fuisce/about.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

models.py - orders

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from carts.models import Cart

from users.models import Profile

STATUS_CHOICES =(
        ("Started", "Started"),
        ("Abandoned", "Abandoned"),
        ("Finished", "Finished"),
    )

class Order(models.Model):
    **user = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)**
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='ABC', unique=True)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('carts.Cart', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="Started")
    sub_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    tax_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    final_total = models.DecimalField(default=10.99, max_digits=1000, decimal_places=2)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __string__(self):
        return self.order_id
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from carts import views as cart_views
from orders import views as order_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='fuisce-home'),
    path('subscription/', views.subscription, name='fuisce-subscription'),
    path('oneoff/', views.oneoff, name='fuisce-oneoff'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='fuisce-about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='fuisce-contact'),
    path('cart/', cart_views.view, name='cart'),
    path('cart/<int:id>/', cart_views.remove_from_cart, name='remove_from_cart'),
    path('cart/<slug>/', cart_views.add_to_cart, name='add_to_cart'),
    path('checkout/', order_views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    **path('orders/', order_views.orders, name='user_orders'),**

]
```

Comment: You are sending an empty context object: how should django now what "user" is?

Comment: @Sean I assume `user` is the currently logged-in user, so what is shown if you just use just `{{ user }}` or `{{ user.order_set }}` ? Just to make sure that the correct template is used and the `user` variable is actually loaded correctly.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks for reply. Yes the user is logged in. When I do {{ user }} the username appears on the page, but when I do {{ user.order_set }} nothing appears on the page. Any idea what the cause is?

Comment: @Sean What happens if you use `print(request.user.order_set)` in your view (not the template) ?

Comment: Can you show your user model? Is this connected to order - it looks like profile is connected not user.

Comment: @Ralf I receive the following error ---- AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'order_set' ---- I had imported the user by doing the following in my models.py  -- from django.contrib.auth.models import User ----- From researching online I believed this should of worked?

Comment: @ger.s.brett Thanks for the reply. Yes here it is ----- from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from fuisce.models import Product

from django.db.models.signals import post_save


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='', upload_to='profile_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile' ------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the question, it seems you have a `ForeignKey` field to `Profile` and not to `User`.

Either change your `ForeignKey` from `Profile` to `User` like this:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'auth.User',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=True)
```

Or use a different lookup in your template:

```
{{ user.profile.order_set.all }}
```